# NetBeans profiler - time is lost somewere?

Tags: java, performance, netbeans, profiling

I tried to profile my application using built-in NetBeans profiler. Result completely make sense, instead of one thing - sum of time for sub-methods and self-time of method is not equal to the value, which is displayed for method. I.e. self-time is 257ms, sub-methods - 110ms, and value for method is 1022. 1022 - 257 - 110 = 655ms. Can you tell me where this time is lost?

Comment: Profilers try to estimate the time spent without spending too much time being accurate so not to impact the results. One thing I have seen profilers do is give too much weight to the method call itself.  This can make methods look more expensive than they are. This may explain why you get different times calculated one way than another. The smaller value is more likely to be accurate IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is dynamic CPU frequency switching turned on? Try disabling it, rerun the profiler calibration and re-profile the project.

In case it doesn't help I would recommend filing an issue for profiler at http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/

Don't forget to attach the sample project (if possible).

Comment: And how can be dynamic CPU frequency turned off?

Comment: Depends on the operating system.
Search http://www.google.de/search?hl=en&q=cpu+frequency+scaling+disable&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=